# Hybris promotion cart total progress

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, discount, promotions

I have products which have percentage discount like %10. When I applied cart total based promotion like free delivery, promotion considers cart total price without percentage discount. But user sees the discounted cart total, so problem occurs.

```
Product price = 100 USD
discount %10
promotion is if cart total >= 95 USD free delivery
we want add delivery cost because after discount total 90 USD
condition apply free cost delivery because takes cart total as 100 USD without discount
```

How can handle this? We are using european1 price and hybris 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the priority of the delivery mode promotion is higher (or equal) than the discount promotion. 
Make sure the discount promotion has a higher priority which will make it get executed first. If the delivery promotion has a lower priority it should be checked afterwards and no longer apply.

Hope this helps

Comment: I make discount with discount row, may be it is not promotion. So when changing priority has not effect.

Comment: Not sure if I understand..  you have two promotions though right?

Comment: One of them is promotion, other is discount row.

Comment: Hi is there a step by step tutorial for creating a percentage discount promotion only for the items with credit card payment in the cart